# Matlab: Matrix Neighbour Extraction

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a large number of images which I've broken down into segments such that their matrices look like:

```
img = [ 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3  
        1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3  
        1 1 1 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3  
        5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 2 3 3 3 ];
```

where each number represents a different region and each region is arbitrarily shaped.  So in this case, region 1 has neighbours 2, 4 and 5, region 2 has neighbours 1, 3 and 4 and so on.

I've extracted all of the regions into separate cells and obtained statistics (mean, variance, etc) which I plan to use to merge regions with statistics within a certain tolerance.  I'm struggling to think of an efficient way to obtain the neighbours of each region to allow that merging to occur.

I have a horrible solution which takes a very long time for even one image:

```
referenceImage = [ 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3;
                    1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3;
                    1 1 1 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3;
                    5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 2 3 3 3];

% Wish to extract each region into a separate cell
lastSP = 5;
sps = 1:lastSP;
% Could be a way to vectorise the below loop but it escapes me
superPixels(lastSP) = struct('Indices', 0, 'Neighbours', 0);
% Split data into separate cells
parfor a = 1 : lastSP
    inds = find(referenceImage == sps(a));
    superPixels(a).Indices = inds;
end

szs = size(referenceImage); % Sizes of RGB Image
for a = 1 : lastSP + 1
    mask = zeros(szs(1), szs(2)); % Just bin mask wanted
    mask(superPixels(a).Indices) = 1; % Mark the region pixels as one
    mask = xor(bwmorph(mask, 'thicken'), mask); % Obtain the outlying regions

    inds = find(mask ==1); % Fetch the external region indices

    neighbours = []; % Have to dynamically grow neighbours matrix
    neigh = 1;  

    for b = 1 : length(inds)
        found = false;
        if ~isempty(neighbours) % Check neighbours first
            for c = 1 : length(neighbours)
                if any(superPixels(neighbours(c)).Indices == inds(b))
                    found = true;
                    break;
                end
            end
        end

        if ~found
           for c = 1 : lastSP + 1 % Check every other region
               if any(superPixels(c).Indices == inds(b))
                    neighbours(neigh) = c;
                    neigh = neigh + 1;
                    break;
                end
           end
        end            
    end  
    superPixels(a).Neighbours = neighbours;
end
```

I'm wondering if this is actually the best way to approach this problem.  I know the very last loop is the main problem but I can't think of another way to reasonably write this, unless I recurse and check the neighbours of known neighbours.

Any help or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Your code is not runnable as is. You should define all variables so that we can paste it onto Matlab command window and get a result. Or: for your example `img`,  tell exactly what the desired output would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple (but probably not maximally efficient) solution is to dilate each region mask to pick neighbors:

```
labels = unique(img);
nLabels = length(labels);
neighbors = cell(nLabels,1);

for iLabel = 1:nLabels
   msk = img == labels(iLabel);
   adjacentPixelMask = imdilate(msk,true(3)) & ~msk;
   neighbors{iLabel} = unique(img(adjacentPixelMask));
end

neighbors{1}
ans =
     2
     4
     5
```

Comment: @SeanTheStudent: I believe that you're using the same approach as I, but that you're somehow checking each pixel's neighbors, while it is faster to look at the regions' neighbors instead.

Comment: Awesome!  Transitions from a couple of minutes to around 20 seconds per image; huge difference so thanks very much!
I'm a little new to Matlab and its vector/matrix approach so thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jonas, nice! what about considering not only the closest neighbors (say `k=1`), but also to include the neighbors of neighbors (`k=2`) for each superpixel?

Comment: @Tin: neighbors of `1` are `unique(cat(1,neighbors{neighbors{1}}))`. Use the neighbor array to look at the neighbors of your neighbors.

Comment: @Jonas, thanks! So, if I would like to consider `k=3` (neighbors of neighbors of neighbors) or higher, then I could use a recursive function `unique(cat(1,neighbors{neighbors{ii}}))`, where `ii` is a neighbor. Do you think there's a faster way to go?