# Construct adjacency matrix in Matlab from labeled matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, adjacency-matrix

How can I construct adjacency matrix with 4-connected neighborhood algorithm from a matrix which has a structure such that

00000111
11111122
33333222
33334444

I want to indicate that 0 is neighboor with 1 and 1 is neighboor with 2 and 3 etc.
Since the dimensions of  matrix that I want to convert to adjacency matrix will be great as 560680x560680 pixels, I need an efficient algorithm. I thought scanning row by row since consequtive numbers are neighboors if they are on the same row but still it is inefficient since dimension is huge.

Comment: 4- or 8-connected neighborhood?

Comment: @Daniel 4-connected neighborhood.

Comment: Just noticed [we already had this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487090/matlab-matrix-neighbour-extraction), you just need to adapt the neighbourhood mask from `true(3)` to `[0 1 0; 1 1 1;  0 1 0]` to get your 4-connected neighbourhood. Give it a try, I am not sure how the performance will be in your case.

Comment: Thank you it worked fast enough @Daniel